# Can I call a python script inside a tensorflow function?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to call a python script which calculates the sign of matrix inside a tensorflow function. I am not understanding how to do it.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: what is "sign of a matrix"?

Comment: By sign I meant if the element of a matrix is greater than 0 assign 1 else -1. I want to know how to call a normal python function in tensorflow function. Thank you

Comment: You can use `tf.cond` and `tf.where`, I'll mention how in the answer below

Comment: A normal python function may not be differentiable and gradients may not flow in that case. It is always better to use `tf` functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tf.where` checks for the `condition` and if true evaluates the first parameter else the second parameter to `tf.where`.

An example is illustrated below:

```py
# a is the array you want to threshold

cond = tf.greater(a, tf.zeros(tf.shape(a)))
thresholded_matrix = tf.where(cond, tf.ones(tf.shape(a)), -1.*tf.ones(tf.shape(a)))
```

Alternatively, you can also use `tf.sign`.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.Thank u its working for me.

Comment: @user12902339 can you please accept this as solution and/or upvote it?

Comment: @user12902339 You can accept an answer by clicking on big-gray check button on the left side. For upvoting, click the gray triangle on the top.